# JS function doesn't work when AJAX request is done (Maybe a $(this) problem)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My site has a form which insert records in a database using ajax, at the same time, it "refreshes" a table also using AJAX in the same page showing this new record.

So I have the JS code

```
// New Record Div
$('button[type=submit]').click(function() {
    // Read all the form content
    var creditor = $('#selCreditor').val();
    var reason = $('#txtReason').val();
    var value = $('#txtValue').val();
    var debtor = $('#selDebtor').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index/insert/creditor/'+creditor+'/reason/'+reason+'/value/'+value+'/debtor/'+debtor,
    success: function() {
        $('#status').slideDown();
        $('#latestRecords').fadeOut();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index/latest',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#latestRecords').fadeIn();
            $('#latestRecords').html(html);
        }
        });
    }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Basically, it inserts a new record in the database, then on success, it requests a page which contains only the table and populate the div with the returned data. It's sort of a refresh when the data is submitted. Everything is done using AJAX.

I've uploaded the situation image for a better understanding.  [image](http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/4344000/4344071_8da9.png)

### The Problem

Everything goes fine until you try to delete a "refreshed" table row. Without the AJAX (only press F5) I can delete any row I want through the delete button, but when I insert a row and the try to delete any row in the table won't do. This is the Delete button code

```
// TR Fading when deleted
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'history/delete/id/'+$(this).attr('id')
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).remove(); });
    $('#latest')
    return false;
});
```

I suspect that the problem is `$(this)` which not refers to the delete button element once the table is refreshed, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You might want to include an example of your HTML so that people can see the relationship of the elements better. I.E. from your code examples I've no idea where an element with a class of 'delete' is exactly, which may help to determine why you're having a problem with $(this)

Comment: They already solved the problem, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the entire table is being reloaded then `.click()` wont work as it will have lost the elements it was applied to. Try using `.live()` instead.

e.g.

```
$('.delete').live('click',function(){...});
```

Also assign `$(this)` to a variable and use the variable instead, it can help make the code a bit clearer I think. e.g. `var $deleteButton = $(this);`

Comment: What about the event when the table hasn't reloaded yet? Does .live() still works?

Comment: `.live()` should work at all times for any element that has the selector supplied to it.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at jquerys [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/), i think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nalums anwser, Who stated that you can use `.live()` — which will work even if you add dynamic elements through jQuery — you should instead use for most occasions the newer `.delegate()` (*version added: 1.4.2*)

Could be used in this fashion:

```
$("table").delegate("td", "hover", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

Or check out [api.jquery.com/delegate/](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for more information.

Comment: What's the difference between `$("table").delegate("td"...` and `$("table td").live(...)`?